# Is there a limit of files / folders that can be stored within a folder?

Tags: c#, windows, filesystems

We're developing an application that targets every OS from Windows XP SP 3 up to Windows 8. The user has the possibility to trigger some actions that result in storing files on the harddrive. Currently, we're creating for each action the user performs a folder with a unique name in a specific target-folder.

The current Structure looks like:

```
MyTargetFolder
|
|-- 0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e
|     |--- SomeFile.txt
|     |--- AnotherFile.txt
|     
|-- 7c9e6679-7425-40de-944b-e07fc1f90ae7
|     |--- SomeFile.txt
|     |--- AnotherFile.txt
.
.
```

I'm wondering, if there is a specific maximum amount of folders, that can be stored within another folder - maybe dependent on the OS, maybe dependent on the Filesystem (Fat32, NTFS, ...?).

- If there is a limit - what is it?
- If there isn't a limit for one folder - is there a limit of folders in total on a complete drive?
- What happens, when i try to create a folder from my C# application using `Directory.CreateDirectory` and the maximum amount of folders has been reached?
- Regarding performance / indexing - is it faster, to change our structure and group folders into folders?

Something like this:

```
MyTargetFolder
|
|-- AllFoldersStartingWith0
|     |
|     |-- 0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e
|           |--- SomeFile.txt
|           |--- AnotherFile.txt
|
|-- AllFoldersStartingWith7
|     |
|     |-- 7c9e6679-7425-40de-944b-e07fc1f90ae7
|           |--- SomeFile.txt
|           |--- AnotherFile.txt    .
.
```

(Note: Of course we got more than 2 folders in production, as every action the user performs creates a folder, and we're taking GUIDs as foldernames.)

Comment: Have a look at http://superuser.com/questions/446282/max-files-per-directory-on-ntfs-vol-vs-fat32

Comment: Also, note that file methods usually have a maximum length of 250 characters for the path.  If your path (e.g. \RootDirectory\SubDirectory\file.txt) is longer than 250 characters then it will cause problems.  You can (sortof) work around the problem by mapping drives to subfolders, but that can cause issues later on depending on how you try to use the files.

Comment: @MHOOS So it only depends on the FileSystem being used and not on the windows version? He mentions "*Maximum number of files in a single folder: 65,534*" - are files in this case equivalent to folders? The files being stored in a folder is in my case around ~10 to 50, so i should not bother about the files, i'm worried about the folders itself.

Comment: At least on NTFS what matters is the total number of [MFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Master_File_Table) entries. Each directory/file has an MFT record. A data file entry will have at least one `$DATA` attribute in the record, usually anonymous, e.g. `SomeFile.txt::$DATA`, but you can add alternate data streams (ADS), e.g. `SomeFile.txt:metadata:$DATA`. A directory has an `$INDEX_ROOT` attribute, and possibly extended with an `$INDEX_ALLOCATION`. But a 'directory' is also allowed to have alternate data streams, e.g. `MyTargetFolder:log:$DATA`.

Answer (score 0):

Every Windows version has a its own limits on the number of items [Files+folders] it can store in a particlare folder. Although this limit has increased with x64 bits systems, the number itself is no longer the issue in comparison to the raw performance. Windows appears to become extremely sluggish as the number of items [files or folders] in a particular folder increases. You definitly need to think [or re-think] the strategy for accessing these files.

Answer (score 0):

If you go straight to the NT kernel API, 10m item directories perform very well, and there is a 32767 character path limit not 260. You also need not store your filenames as GUIDs as NTFS will directly store and index your files as GUIDs for you i.e. to open a path in notepad you simply enter the volume guid and the file guid and it "just works". The only shortfall is that you cannot choose the GUID I believe as NTFS allocates it for you. More about the direct GUID feature is at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/28/10134679.aspx.

You might now worry about the hassle of talking directly to the NT kernel. If so, you may find proposed Boost.AFIO (https://boostgsoc13.github.io/boost.afio/doc/html/afio.html) of use. Disclaimer: I'm its author.